# Realm query equalTo results in nullpointerexception

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to make a query in realm. But I keep getting a null pointer exception in equalTo("id", 38)

This is the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at io.realm.RealmQuery.getColumnIndices(RealmQuery.java:140)
    at io.realm.RealmQuery.equalTo(RealmQuery.java:199)
    at es.treenovum.paedocuments.services.OfflineService$WidgetOpsNewest.loadTags(OfflineService.java:340)
    at es.treenovum.paedocuments.services.OfflineService$WidgetOpsNewest.doInBackground(OfflineService.java:228)
    at es.treenovum.paedocuments.services.OfflineService$WidgetOpsNewest.doInBackground(OfflineService.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 3 more
```

The exception happens on the equalTo line here:

```
Category categoryResult = realm.where(Category.class)
      .equalTo("id", category.getId())
      .findFirst();
```

The int category.getId() is not null or empty. realm neither.

If its the first time I run the app the db is empty. Would that cause this? Shouldn't there return null or 0 in result instead of throwing an exception?

EDIT: Category Class added. All getters and setters generated by eclipse.

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.RealmClass;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@RealmClass
public class Category extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("text")
    private String text;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your category class look like?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I've update the question with the category class

Comment: What version of Realm are using, because that error should not be possible on the latest version of Realm which is 0.78.0?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior that is the version I was using.

Comment: Odd, without further investigation it is hard to say. Can you create a minimal project reproducing the case and create an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-java ?

Comment: Getting the same error. Conditions are unclear. I ran into this while writing CRUD tests for realm model. Looks like internal `HashMap columns` in `RealmQuery` object is null at some time. I guess `Realm.columnIndices.get(clazz.getSimpleName())` in constructor is the reason. Maybe realm did not iniliatize its `columnIndices` yet. Interesting that this code works in app, but not in test.